# How to use APEX checkbox group values in the where clause of a query

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using APEX 20.2.
I have a checkbox group with 3 different values:

[image: CHECKBOX GROUP]

The values checked in this group are used to filter a query and I'm not sure how to write the where clause
Here is what I have:

```
SELECT Null as link, PERSONNE_EN_CHARGE as label, count(*) as value 
FROM FLYWAY_MEP_HISTORY 
WHERE STATUT_MEP='SUCCESS' 
AND (DATE_MEP BETWEEN to_date(:DATE_DEBUT,'DD/MM/YYYY') AND to_date(:DATE_FIN ,'DD/MM/YYYY')+1)
OR (:DATE_DEBUT is null and :DATE_FIN is null)
AND (UPPER(ENVIRONNEMENT) is null or UPPER(ENVIRONNEMENT) IN (:ENVIRONNEMENT))
GROUP BY PERSONNE_EN_CHARGE
ORDER BY 2;
```

the part I'm not sure of is this part:

```
UPPER(ENVIRONNEMENT) IN (:ENVIRONNEMENT))
```

How can I use the values of the checkbox group in the where clause?

If I debug the page I can see this in the devlopper console

[image: debug]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select multiple values in Apex, they are separated by colon. So, if you split that value into rows, you can use it as a subquery. In your case:

```
...
or UPPER(ENVIRONNEMENT) IN 
  (select regexp_substr(:ENVIRONNEMENT, '[^:]+', 1, level)
   from dual
   connect by level <= regexp_count(:ENVIRONMENT, ':') + 1
  )
```

Comment: Note that Apex has a nice built in splitting function that makes this easier: `or UPPER(ENVIRONNEMENT) in (select column_value from table(apex_string.split(:ENVIRONNEMENT,':')))`